# How do I remove the decimal point when uploading a data set containing ICD-10 codes? Also, how can I use proc sql to create a cohort?

Tags: sas

I am a beginner is SAS and am working on a research project where I am supposed to use a running list of 300 ICD-10 codes to find participants in my study and I'm having a lot of trouble. I am creating my data set and cannot figure out 1. how to remove the decimal from the icd10 code,2. there is a comma in the beginning of my ICD-10 code in the output table and 3. the last character of the icd-10 code (alpha character) will not show up in my output table. Here is my code:

```
data EE2106;
infile '/home/u62039685/DatasetEE2016/PUF_ICD10_DCODE2016.csv';
input inc_key 9. ICD10_dcode$;
run;
```

```
*remove decimal from ICD10 code";
    data EE2106final;
    set ee2106;
    length ICD10_dcode;
    ICD10_dcode=compress(icd10,".");
run;
```

```
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a numeric constant.  
 
ERROR 352-185: The length of numeric variables is 3-8.
 
 72         ICD10_dcode=compress(icd10,".");
 ERROR: Numeric length cannot be used with character variable ICD10_dcode.
```

I am also trying to figure out how to create a cohort(find participants) matching with a running list of over 300 ICD-10 codes. I clearly cannot use If, then statements so I hear Proc SQL data step can be helpful? Any tips or suggestions on how I should use this?

I tried using a data step instead of proc import and trying to find ways to note that my ICD10_dcode variable is alphanumeric. I also tried using the length statement to help remove the decimal but have not been successful.

Regarding the proc sql, I tried this code in the past before deciding that I needed a data step instead of proc import and was not successful either. Here is the code I used:

```
proc sql;
create table cohort as
select a.*, b.*
from cohort2016 a
inner join icd10codes b
on put (a.inc_key, best10.) = b.diag_code;
select * from cohort;
quit;
```

Comment: Why remove the dot (`.`)?  How is your list maintained?  Is it a separate data set? Does you csv file contains ICD codes that themselves have commas?  If so how do you separate the data from the delimiter.  Show some sample csv and sample running list.

Comment: I would like to remove the (.) from the original data set because the running list of ICD-10 codes I have in a separate document do not have a decimal. For example, participant one in the medical record may have an ICD-code of S32.030A but in the csv file containing the codes needed would be listed as S32030A

Answer (score 0):

The LENGTH statement sets the storage length (and the TYPE) of the variable. It has nothing to do with whether the value has a period in it or not.

But in your code you forgot to actually say what LENGTH to define the variable to have.  In your first data step you left SAS default to using $8 for the length of the variable ICD10_dcode.  So to replicate the same thing with a LENGTH statement you would want

```
length ICD10_dcode $8 ;
```

Also notice that your first data step is not defining the ICD10 variable your second data step is expecting.  It is also not reading the values properly for an actual delimited file (such as a CSV file).  You do not want to use FORMATTED input as that will not honor the delimiters.  Add the DSD option to the INFILE statement. If the your comma delimited file is using some other delimiter than a comma then also add the DLM= option.  You can add the statements to created the new variable to the same step if you want.

```
data EE2106;
  infile '/home/u62039685/DatasetEE2016/PUF_ICD10_DCODE2016.csv' dsd ;
  input inc_key  ICD10 $;
  length ICD10_dcode $8;
  ICD10_dcode=compress(icd10,".");
run;
```

Comment: With those additions, the following edits came up:  ERROR 22-322: Expecting a numeric constant.  
 
 ERROR 352-185: The length of numeric variables is 3-8.

Comment: You still have to specify an actual LENGTH in the LENGTH statement. Fixed.